# Can't retrieve method annotation into Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, annotations, cucumber-jvm

I try to retrieve Cucumber annotations to make a content assist plugin. But i don't know why my code does not work. The reflexion api return me  null for the method.getDeclaredAnnotations().

```
public List<String> getStepDefinition() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        String location = Platform.getPreferencesService().
                  getString("myPref", "jarLocation", null, null);
        if(location != null) {
            File f = new File(location);
            URL url = f.toURI().toURL();  
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
            URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("myStepDefinitionFile");
            Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if(method.isAnnotationPresent(Soit.class)) {
                    Soit annotation = method.getAnnotation(Soit.class);
                    annotation.value();
                }
            }
            cl.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In debug mode, i see that the class was found and i can list all methods. But i can't list the method annotations. The reflexion api don't find them.

This is the Soit.class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@StepDefAnnotation
@Documented
public @interface Soit {
    /**
     * @return a regular expression
     */
    String value();

    /**
     * @return max amount of milliseconds this is allowed to run for. 0 (default) means no restriction.
     */
    long timeout() default 0;
}
```

And this is the method annoted with it :

```
@Override
    @Soit("^ok$")
    public void ok() {
        this.driver.ok();
    }
```

Comment: Is the annotation contained in the same jar file?

Comment: I only understood the "non" part, I think the annotation class has to be available also from the `URLClassLoader`, or from it's parents. It is not an error if an annotation class is not on the classpath, in that case you just can't retrieve it using reflection.

Comment: Sorry miss copy past, No, the annotations are defined in cucumber jar, used in another, and I try to analyze them via reflection in a third.In my plugin i have the cucumber classes and annotations as dependency